# Android opens old version of my Expo App after update

Tags: expo, react-native

I have updated my android app with the new version which is an expo app but when users open the app (after updating it) it opens with the old version.

Unless users delete the existing app from phone and reinstall from google play store, it does not get update.

You can see my app.json file in the below, please help.

```
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "ABC",
        "description": "ABC Description",
        "slug": "abc-abc-abc",
        "version": "2.0.2",
        "privacy": "unlisted",
        "sdkVersion": "39.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain"
        },
        "updates": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
        "ios": {
            "bundleIdentifier": "com-abc-abc",
            "buildNumber": "2.0.2",
            "supportsTablet": true
        },
        "android": {
            "package": "com.abc",
            "versionCode": 45,
            "adaptiveIcon": {
                "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
                "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
            },
            "permissions": ["WRITE_CALENDAR", "READ_CALENDAR"]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
"privacy": "unlisted" to "privacy": "public"
```

fixed the problem